# Sorting unique identification number

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have sorted a set of records in desc order by instead of get PK- 10 on top I'm getting PK - 9 why is it so,Even if you remove the prefix and sort its returning 9. Please suggest a solution in sql server or C#

```
UniqueIdentificationNo
PK - 9
PK - 8
PK - 7
PK - 6
PK - 4
PK - 2
PK - 10

SELECT  [UniqueIdentificationNo]
    FROM [Product] order by [UniqueIdentificationNo] desc
```

C# code, int.parse returns error, This code also returns PK - 9

```
 var lastProduct = DbContext.Products.OrderByDescending(x => int.Parse(
            (x.UniqueIdentificationNo ?? string.Empty).Replace(prefix, string.Empty).Trim())).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Looks like your variable is string. Cast `UniqueIdentificationNo` to integer

Comment: what is the data type of UniqueIdentificationNo ?

Comment: Can you change it to integer in db?

Comment: No it should be varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sqlserver you need to modify order by like below.

```
SELECT [UNIQUEIDENTIFICATIONNO]
FROM   product
ORDER  BY CONVERT(INT, RIGHT([UNIQUEIDENTIFICATIONNO], 
                Len([UNIQUEIDENTIFICATIONNO]) - Charindex('-', [UNIQUEIDENTIFICATIONNO]))) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If the resulting List looks like this:

```
List<string> UINumber = new List<string>(){ "PK - 9",
                                            "PK - 8",
                                            "PK - 7",
                                            "PK - 6",
                                            "PK - 4",
                                            "PK - 2",
                                            "PK - 10"};
```

Then You can use the following code for sorting them in descending order:

```
var soretedList = UINumber.OrderByDescending(x =>Convert.ToInt16(
                                             x.Substring(x.IndexOf("- ") + 1))
                                            ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the data starts in the same way (`PK -`), you can do as follows.

```
SELECT 
    UNIQUEIDENTIFICATIONNO
FROM 
    product
ORDER BY 
    RIGHT(UNIQUEIDENTIFICATIONNO, LEN(UNIQUEIDENTIFICATIONNO) - 4) * 1
```